# Should aggregate involve a read-lock in database?

Tags: concurrency, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I read the Eric Evan's book about **DDD**, chapter **Aggregates**.

When dealing with the Order/OrderLine example, it is stated:

> When both users have saved their changes, an Order will be stored in the
>   database that violates the invariant of the domain model. An important
>   business rule has been broken. And nobody even knows. Clearly, locking
>   a single line-item isn’t an adequate safeguard. **If, instead, we locked
>   an entire Order at a time**, the problem would have been prevented.

I well know that the essence of Aggregate is to protect invariants with a single wrapped database transaction.

But should every aggregate be specified **with a read-lock at database side** to prevent potential concurrency issues (race condition) while modifying this aggregate simultaneously by multiple users?

Is the **real meaning** of making an aggregate is **to gather some elements for a read-lock** at database side?

Any clarification about this would make me happy.

Comment: Or maybe it's all about optimistic locking ... not read-locking..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the two are orthogonal:

**The goal of the aggregate design is to establish a consistency boundary and protect the invariants within that boundary. The goal of the locking design is to enable an appropriate level of concurrency within the application.**

What this means is that with the same aggregate design, different locking mechanisms might make sense (depending on the non-functional requirements of the application).

Answer (score 3):

> I well know that the essence of Aggregate is to protect invariants
>   with a single wrapped database transaction.

Is it? Aggregate roots are there as a consistency boundary around their own invariants. Given that persistence happens across a network in a completely different process, how can an aggregate in a process ever hope to guarantee consistency around something that is WAY outside its control?

The essence of DDD is separation of domain and infrastructure concerns; aggregates should be couched in terms of the **domain** modelled (Orders, Products, Customers) and everything else (databases, persistence, locking, transactions) are **infrastructure** and should not be polluting your domain model.